# What makes my PhpStorm keep on de-exclude one "PHP added" directory

Tags: ide, phpstorm

I am using PhpStorm, which is great. But one of my project is quite big and has a lot of dependencies, and the indexing of all this code is really long. Thus I really pay attention to exclude all the directories that I don't need. And it works... except for one 'vendor' folder.

This one specific directory reappears constantly in my "PHP > Include paths" settings, even though it's set as excluded on the Project tree (see screenshot).
So my IDE keeps on re-indexing it and that lasts very long, even if I empty the "PHP > Include Paths" settings, clear the cache and restart the IDE.

I don't know what background task changes this setting under the hood, but there must be one. One clue is that the specific folder is indexed during a step called "indexing 'PHP' added files" as you can see in the screenshot below.

[image: The excluded 'vendor' folder still being indexed]

Any idea of what makes this evil folder come back and back again as Terminator?

Answer (score 0):

So, I am glad I found the source of this annoyance.

It came from the fact that the `PHP > composer >  settings > path to composer.json` pointed to one of of the vendors folders. So I guess PhpStorm de-excluded the whole `vendor` folder in order to have access to it (it may be a bug in Phpstorm).

I replaced this setting by the correct one, and the indexing process is correct now!